# Show Loading Gif in Ajax Call if completion takes longer then 0.5 Seconds

Tags: javascript, ajax

Im showing a loading gif `beforeSend` and hide it after `complete` insid an ajax function. Is there any way other then `timeout` to show the gif only if the call takes longer than 0.5 seconds for example?

```
    ...
    beforeSend:function(){
        $(".preloader").show();
    },                   
    success: function(data) {                       
        $("#tsprices").html(data);                  
        // console.log(data)
    },
    complete: function() {
        $(".preloader").hide();                 
    },
    ...
```

Comment: What's wrong with `setTimeout`?

Comment: @GeneralGrievance - nothing, but im interested in another solution where you get infos about the execution time maybe

Comment: I think it would be good if you added some details about what your end goal is. If you have a snippet example, even better.